# addition of int and str

Tags: python

hello i am reading this python book and one of the exercises says:

> Write a function named right_justify that takes a string named s as a parameter and prints the string with enough leading spaces so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

ok so i have the following code that prints 70 spaces and the string 'allen'

```
def right_justify(s):
    print s
right_justify(' ' * 70 + 'Allen')
```

but when i try to subtract the number of spaces from the string 'Allen'

```
sub = len('allen')
def right_justify(s):
    print s
right_justify(' ' * 70 - sub + 'Allen')
```

i get:

> "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'"

why does it work without the sub variable and it doesn't with it? 
I have checked the type of the sub and it comes out as an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
' ' * (70 - sub) + 'Allen'
```

Your code is evaluated as:

```
((' ' * 70) - sub) + 'Allen'
```

That doesn't work because you can't subtract an int from a string.

Comment: yeah i tried that but i added the parenthesis wrong before, i was not on the bad track, i tried with ((' ' * 70 - sub) + 'Allen')

thanks

Comment: @philhxc, if his answer helped click the checkmark next to the answer to indicate that you accept the answer. Also, Jdog's answer has soom good advice.

Answer (score 5):

As Mark says, you need parentheses around your subtraction.

Also you are doing the work of right_justify in the argument you pass. The function simply prints what you give it at the moment.

You should just pass a string, s, and let right_justify do the work on the string (i.e. work out its length then add the appropriate number of white space prior to it) before printing it.

Something like:

```
def right_justify(s):
    sub = len(s)
    new_s = ' ' * (70 - sub) + s 
    print new_s

right_justify('Allen')
```

Comment: Also, this is just an excercise. In real world it is better to use [format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).
i.e.: `print '{:>30}'.format(s)`

Comment: @philberndt The line I pasted does exactly the same as three lines in the function above. And it should be more universal as well.

Answer (score 0):

> def right_justify(s):
>   .     print (' '*(70-len(s))+s)
>   .
>   right_justify('allen')
>                                                                    allen

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Think_Python/Answers#Exercise_3.3